# reading binary from dynamoDB php

Tags: php, binary, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to write and read binary data from DynamoDB using SDK php 2.

I can write the data to the table but when I read it, it comes in a different format how to cast it back to its original binary format.

```
$put_response = $dynamodb->putItem(array(
    'TableName' => 'TableName', 
    'Item' => array(
    'Id' => array( 'S' => 'werwer' ), // Primary Key
    'IV' => array( 'B' => openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(50)),
    'Password' => array( 'B' => $encrypt->EncryptER("asdasd") )
    )
    ));
```

When I read the IV attribute or the Password I get a different value for it, what is the cast that I should do or if there is a function to convert the string back to binary.

This is what I get if I do echo before storing the value in Dynamo �LX�x��ʝ�t]�>0

This is the echo of the variable after reading it from Dynamo GdNMWLt4nZrKnc50XdE+MA==

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing was that the binary data is stored in base64 in DynamoDB even if you provided it in raw format. so to get the raw binary back I had to use

```
base64_decode($response->getPath('Item/IV/B'))
```